# problem with clang application

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, clang, fedora12

I am building an application using clang libraries, I running to a
problem, it will be very helpful if somebody can give some directions.

`#./a.out /home/nmathew/Desktop/algorithms/array.cpp` gives

```
In file included from /home/nmathew/Desktop/algorithms/array.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4.3/iostream:39:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4.3/ostream:39:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4.3/ios:38:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4.3/iosfwd:40:
/usr/include/c++/4.4.3/bits/stringfwd.h:49:48: error: unknown type
name 'char_traits'

a.out: TextDiagnosticPrinter.cpp:293: void clang::TextDiagnosticPrinter::EmitCaretDiagnostic(clang::SourceLocation,clang::SourceRange*, unsigned int, const clang::SourceManager&, const
clang::FixItHint*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned
int, unsigned int): Assertion `LangOpts && "Unexpected diagnostic
outside source file processing"' failed.
Stack dump:
0. /usr/include/c++/4.4.3/bits/stringfwd.h:49:48: current parser token
'char_traits'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

My Include search directories are below.

`#include "..."` search starts here:
`#include <...>` search starts here:
 /usr/include/linux
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.3/include
 /usr/include/c++/4.4.3
 /usr/include/c++/4.4.3/backward
 /usr/include/c++/4.4.3/i686-redhat-linux
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.

and char_traits.h is in /usr/include/c++/4.4.3/bits/, I am using
Fedora 12   32bit system.

My code is listed below

tut01_pp.cpp

```
#include "PPContext.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        if (argc != 2)
        {
                return 0;
        }

        PPContext scope;
        scope.headers.PrintStats();
        const FileEntry *File = scope.fm.getFile(argv[1]);

        if(!File)
        {
               return 0;
        }

        scope.sm.createMainFileID(File, SourceLocation());
        scope.pp->EnterMainSourceFile();
        IdentifierTable identitab(scope.lang);
        MinimalAction action(*(scope.pp));
        Parser parse(*(scope.pp), action);
        parse.ParseTranslationUnit();
        identitab.PrintStats();

        return 0;
}
```

PPContext.h

```
#ifndef PP_CONTEXT
#define PP_CONTEXT

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include <llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h>

#include <clang/Basic/Diagnostic.h>
#include <clang/Basic/TargetInfo.h>
#include <clang/Basic/TargetOptions.h>
#include <clang/Basic/FileManager.h>
#include <clang/Basic/SourceManager.h>
#include <clang/Lex/Preprocessor.h>
#include <clang/Lex/HeaderSearch.h>
#include <clang/Frontend/Utils.h>
#include <clang/Frontend/TextDiagnosticPrinter.h>
#include <clang/Frontend/DiagnosticOptions.h>
#include <clang/Frontend/HeaderSearchOptions.h>
#include <clang/Parse/Action.h>
#include <clang/Parse/Parser.h>
#include "llvm/System/Host.h"
using namespace clang;
using namespace llvm;

struct PPContext {
        PPContext():tdp(ost, options), diag(&tdp), sm(diag), headers(fm)
        {

                TargetOptions target_options;
                target_options.Triple = sys::getHostTriple();
                target_options.CXXABI = "itanium";
                target = TargetInfo::CreateTargetInfo(diag, target_options);
                lang.CPlusPlus = 1;
                pp = new Preprocessor(diag, lang, *target, sm, headers);
                headeropts.EnvIncPath = "/usr/include/linux";
                headeropts.CXXEnvIncPath =
                    "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.3/include/";
                headeropts.Verbose = 1;
                ApplyHeaderSearchOptions(headers, headeropts, lang,
                    llvm::Triple(target_options.Triple));
        };
        ~PPContext()
        {
                delete pp;
                delete target;
        };

        llvm::raw_stdout_ostream ost;
        const DiagnosticOptions options;
        TextDiagnosticPrinter tdp;
        Diagnostic diag;
        LangOptions lang;
        SourceManager sm;
        FileManager fm;
        HeaderSearch headers;
        TargetInfo *target;
        Preprocessor *pp;
        HeaderSearchOptions headeropts;
};
#endif //#ifndef PP_CONTEXT
```

array.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "array.hpp"

using namespace std;



template <class gen>
ARRAY<gen>::ARRAY()
{
 size = MAX;
 ptr = (gen (*)[MAX])new gen[size];
}

template <class gen>
ARRAY<gen>::ARRAY(int array_size)
{
 size = array_size;
 ptr = (gen (*)[])new gen[size];
}

template <class gen>
ARRAY<gen>::~ARRAY()
{
 delete (gen (*)[MAX])ptr;
}

template <class gen>
int ARRAY<gen>::getsize()
{
 return size;
}

template <class gen>
ARRAY<gen>::ARRAY(const ARRAY &orig)
{
 ptr = (gen (*)[MAX])new gen[orig.size];
 memcpy(ptr, orig.ptr, sizeof(gen)*orig.size);
 size = orig.size;
}

template <class gen>
gen& ARRAY<gen>::operator [](unsigned int index)
{
 return *ptr[index];
}

int main(void)
{
 ARRAY <int> intarray;
 intarray[8] = 16;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @nmathew!  I did what I could to reformat the code.  Code should be indented by four spaces; you don't need to use <pre> (which messes up the formatting).  Also, in general, prefer Markdown syntax to HTML tags; the results will probably be less surprising :)

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that template class "char_traits" doesn't exist. This one, actually is defined in "char_traits.h", is not included by "array.cpp".

Although in this file, it reads:

```
/** @file char_traits.h
*  This is an internal header file, included by other library headers.
*  You should not attempt to use it directly.
*/
```

But you can still try to include it and make clang happy.